# Log files are not getting created in python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, logging, python-logging

Created Logger file and accessing the same in another file. But not getting any logging detailes.

```
import logging

class LogGen:
    @staticmethod
    def logGen():
        logging.basicConfig(filename=".\\Logs\\automation.log",
                            format='%(asctime)s: %(levelname)s: %(message)s', datefmt='%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p')
        logger=logging.getLogger()
        logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
        return logger
```

On access this from the below code, this is not creating the logfile in my project.

```
import pytest
from selenium import webdriver
from pageObjects.LoginPage import Login
from utilities.readProperties import Readconfig
from utilities.customLogger import LogGen

class Test_001_Login:
    baseurl=Readconfig.getApplicationURL()
    username=Readconfig.getUseremail()
    password=Readconfig.getUserpassword()
    logger=LogGen.logGen()

    def test_homepage_title(self,setup):
        self.logger.info("**************Test_Case_001_HP********")
        self.driver=setup
        self.driver.get(self.baseurl)
        act_title=self.driver.title

        if act_title=="Your store. Login":
            assert True
            self.logger.info("**************Test case 1 pass *******")
            self.driver.close()
        else:
            self.driver.save_screenshot(".\\Screenshot\\"+"test_homepage_title.png")
            self.logger.error("**************Test_Case_001_Fail********")
            self.driver.close()
            assert False


    def test_login(self,setup):
        self.logger.info("**************2********")
        self.driver=setup
        self.driver.get(self.baseurl)
        self.lp=Login(self.driver)
        self.lp.setUserName(self.username)
        self.lp.setPassword(self.password)
        self.lp.clickLogin()
        print("test case2")
        actual_title=self.driver.title
        if actual_title=="Dashboard / nopCommerce administration1":
            assert True
            self.logger.info("**************Test_Case_002_Pass********")
            self.driver.close()
        else:
            self.driver.save_screenshot(".\\Screenshot\\" + "test_login.png")
            self.logger.error("**************Test_Case_002_Fail********")
            self.driver.close()
            assert False
```

Created Logger file and accessing the same in another file. But not getting any logging detailes.

Answer (score 0):

If you change the path from:

```
filename=".\\Logs\\automation.log",
```

to:

```
filename="./Logs/automation.log",
```

I think it might work!

Comment: Tried. This is not working. logging.basicConfig(filename="./Logs/automation.log",
                            format='%(asctime)s: %(levelname)s: %(message)s', datefmt='%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p')

Answer (score 0):

## It worked with **force=True**
Use the below syntax. Thanks ALL

logging.basicConfig(filename="./Logs/automation.log",
format='%(asctime)s: %(levelname)s: %(message)s', datefmt='%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p', force=True)